# How to defend against stored XSS inside a JSP attribute value in a form

Tags: jsp, jstl, xss, owasp, esapi

**Question** How to defend against stored XSS inside a JSP attribute value in a form?

The initial code is like

```
<form ..>
    <input value="<c:out value="${name}"/>" type="text" />
</form>
```

Using c:out :

```
<input value="<c:out value="${name}"/>" type="text" />
```

or esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="esapi" uri="http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API" %>
<input value="<esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>${name}</esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>" type="text" />
```

**My first thought** From what I read, the esapi encoding is the safest way. I don't think c:out is safe enough when we are writing the value of an attribute. Based on the [Owasp cheat sheet to prevent xss](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#rule-1---html-escape-before-inserting-untrusted-data-into-html-element-content) escaping should be done different depending on the context where the value is used - attribute value in this case. `c:out` only escapes for HTML sensitive characters, so only these characters: & < > " ' /.

An example of vulnerability: it is possible someone deletes by mistake the characters " or ' surrounding the attribute value. The page will still be valid HTML and working well. But if the value to be inserted in the attribute is `something onclick=alert(1)` then, because c:out will not escape anything, we will have the html `<input value=something onclick=alert(1) ...` which will execute javascript on click.

Comment: You've kindof answered your own question here.  Yes, you would use the `encodeForHTMLAttribute` for exactly the reason you specified:  Depending on the attribute someone could add script events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @avgvstvs for confirming this approach. So the safe way to go is indeed `encodeForHTMLAttribute`